# Grammatical category - derivational and inflectional morphology

Tags: grammar

I am taking a linguistics course and got confused at the meaning of grammatical category. I saw it being used to describe the difference between these two terms: Derivational morphology and inflectional morphology.

Inflectional morphology: no change in the grammatical category (e.g. give, given,
gave, gives )

Derivational morphology: change in category (e.g. process, processing, processable, processor,
processabilty)

1) Are verbs, adjectives, etc in different grammatical categories ? Are these what the categories are about ?

2) How does adding -ing to process change its category ? It it because process has multiple meanings to it ? And adding -ing turns it into a verb ?

3) What about adding -ing to give to make it into giving ? They are both still verbs.

EDIT: Okay I think I understand now. Derivational morphemes **can** change the grammatical category of a word; it **does not always** change it. I was under the impression that derivational morphemes must change the grammatical category of a word. Is this correct ?

Comment: It's a category that somehow applies to grammar.

Comment: @HotLicks I have added some more questions and was hoping you could clarify my doubt.

Comment: Try this takeaway sheet on [Inflection and Derivation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf). "Grammatical category" in this context means part of speech. So nominalization, verbalization, etc. are always derivational, and anything paradigmatic is always inflectional.